# How to remove spaces in a string?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I have code where the user inputs a string and I need the spaces to be removed in the middle of multiple words.

Here is what I have:

```
`System.out.println("Enter your choice:\n"
            + "Type 'Player Name' to search for a player based off their name.\n"
            + "Type 'Player School' to search for a player based off their school\n"
            + "Type 'Team Location' to search for a team based off their location.\n"
            + "Type 'Team Mascot' to search for a team based off their mascot.\n");
    String choice = input.next();
    choice = choice.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    System.out.println(choice);
    switch(choice.toLowerCase()){
    case "playername":
        searchPlayer();
        break;
    case "playerschool":
        searchSchool();
        break;
    case "teamlocation":
        searchLocation();
        break;
    case "teammascot":
        searchMascot();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Yet to be implemented");
        break;
    }`
```

This gives me no errors however it always returns the default case when I include spaces.
I put the line to print the choice to see why it wasn't working and when I run this it only keeps the first word.
For example if I type "Player Name" it will return "player".

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for `next()`?

Comment: What is the console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `input.next()` with [`input.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to take whole line of input into consideration. `input.next()` saves an input to the place of delimiter, which by default is one or more spaces.